# What was there before the big bang

Tags: time, early-universe

we know that our universe is expanding, but we must agree to the fact that it has a limit. It just cant expand till infinity. Eventually there will be a end to time. I thought alot about this and i have a idea that before big bang there was nothing except time and a room like structure in which the big bang happened and the walls of the room are the limits of the universe. It does not mean all there was before big bang a room, but it was the room in which our universe came to existence. After The Big Crunch i believe the room will contain nothing it just like before big bang. Now I want to know that does this idea of mine have any logic?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a non-starter as a question: this site is not for discussing personal theories, and it is built on a lot of assumptions that strongly contradict standard theories in physics and cosmology. You may want to check out what the standard cosmological theories say, and note why they do not make use of things before our outside the universe.

Comment: Asking what was before the big bang isn't truly a personal theory. @Anders Sandberg. In this case is the "there" which poses a problem :)

Comment: Well it sounds like a model ... but it seems troublesome, because the current models (AFAIK) state there was no time "before".

Comment: The headline question "What was there before the big bang?" is a duplicate of many others on this forum. Have you looked at them? just search for "before big bang".  The text of the question floats a personal theory which, as @AndersSandberg says, is not really what this site is for. Many of the answers to the other questions might illuminate some of the issues with this theory though.  So, I'm afraid I'm voting to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: *we must agree to the fact that it has a limit* No we don't have to agree with that and if you look up "the Big Rip" and "the Big Chill" you'll see why other models of the future of the universe exist.